# What is a Complete Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Complete Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Complete Words™ | Not Complete Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| Ben | Bill |
| Beat | Slap |
| Geek | Nerd |
| Abbey | Church |
| Aching | Tiring |
| Balding | Receding |
| Abdicating | Renouncing |

CSV version:

```
Complete Words™, Not Complete Words™
Ben,Bill
Beat,Slap
Geek,Nerd
Abbey,Church
Aching,Tiring
Balding,Receding
Abdicating,Renouncing
```

These aren't the only Complete Words™, there are others that exist.

As a bonus, (when it's possible to do so) I will award a bounty to the person that finds the longest Complete Word. This must be a real word (in English). The bounty will be awarded 24 hours after the accepted answer.

If I'm not allowed to do the above, please tell me to edit.

Edit: Correct answer has been identified and accepted at 22:45 GMT 7th March 2018.

Comment: After seeing the solution, I have to ask: why "complete"? I don't see how the property is related to the name.

Comment: @Deusovi Sorry I missed that, nobody has solved that part. I'll not say just yet in case somebody comes up with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Complete Word satisfies the property that

> If we convert the letters into numbers corresponding to their position in the alphabet, the answer is 7 times the length of the word.

Examples

> ACHING = 1+3+8+9+14+7 = 42 = 7*6 
>  GEEK = 7+5+5+11 = 28 = 7*4 
>  ABDICATING = 1+2+4+9+3+1+20+9+14+7 = 70 = 7*10

Bonus suggestion

> Amidocaffeine = 91 = 7*13

Apologies for the edits, I made several incorrect calculations before arriving at the answer.

Comment: i'm always curious how one can find an answer to these quickly;  Is there like software or algorithm for these, or it just come to your sense?  However if there IS such exists please do not provide links as I do not want to destroy these fun riddles

Comment: @Alex, for these 'What is a ___ word?' puzzles, I always employ a few simple strategies at the beginning to try and see the connection - alphabet association, positions of letters on the keyboard, numeric substitution, morse code, etc. Sometimes you get an easy win that way. For the bonus part I did use python with a standard dictionary (although not guaranteed to contain all viable words).

Comment: awesome thanks! Yea it make sense to have codes to decode these riddle.  But you will need the right strategies you mentions before going there i guess.

Answer (score 5):

If [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)'s answer is correct, I would guess one of these being the longest Complete Word™:

> SEMIACADEMICAL = 19 + 5 + 13 + 9 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 5 + 13 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 12 = 98/7 = 14
>
>  CHROOCOCCACEAE = 3 + 8 + 18 + 15 + 15 + 3 + 15 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 1 + 5 = 98/7 = 14

A slightly shorter, but much more common, Complete Word™ is:

> BACKBREAKING = 2 + 1 + 3 + 11 + 2 + 18 + 5 + 1 + 11 + 9 + 14 + 7 = 84/7 = 12

Comment: I awarded you the bounty for the longest Complete word, specifically this was for the word Backbreaking. Other words put forward were not recognized in the dictionarys I looked in.

Answer (score 3):

The set of complete words is a closed. So, a complete word plus another complete word is also a complete word. We can thus construct words from other words. For instance *geekabdicating* is one such word, which probably is not accepted as a solution. If we restrict ourselves to dictionary words

> we can get *Chroococcaceae* (I guess it is originally Latin), which is a cyanobacteria family. One letter longer than *Amidocaffeine* :-)